# Xcode doesn't open a project normally

Tags: xcode

I'm using Xcode 4.1 and it has always worked perfectly but today something wrong has happened.   Instead of opening my project as it usually does it opens just code editor and nothing else. I have restarted my computer but it doesn't help. Other projects are opened normally. Can you give me a hint about what's going on and what should i do to fix it?

Comment: i have this problem too, quite often, and yes it starts with upgrading to xcode 4.1...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

View --> Show Toolbar ,
View --> Show Assistant Editor ,
View --> Show Project navigator

and so on.

Answer (score 9):

The solution, as others wrote before, is to reopen the missing panes and toolbar via the menu.

The cause of the problem is simple: If you open a source file in its own window (by double clicking it in the navigator or so) it just shows the editor pane. if you then close the main project window and the single source window afterwards, Xcode saves that last window state as the current view configuration in the project.

The intermediate solution is to never close the project window before closing all other source windows. But Apple should really fix this stupid bug. It has been around for too long.

Answer (score 4):

Go to

> View --> Show Toolbar.

I've had this before, don't know how it happened, but this fixed it.